# URLMapping to direct all request to a single controller/action

Tags: grails, groovy, urlmappings.groovy

I like to develop an API manager. I want, one single controller to accept all requests.

How can I direct all web requests to the same controller/action, where I should decide for farther processing.

I do not know how to configure the URLMappings.groovy. Possibly I could do that with filter but again I do not know.

I will appreciate your support.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `URLMappings.groovy`,

```
static mappings = {
    "/**"(controller: "foo", action: "bar")
}
```

will direct all URLs to `FooController`'s `bar` action.