# How to map all requests to a controller go to one method and access the original parameter

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails-config

I have a controller where I'm trying to set defaults based on the url - but have all of the requests going to one controller.
Trying to extend the answer in : [URLMapping to direct all request to a single controller/action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595695/urlmapping-to-direct-all-request-to-a-single-controller-action)

I did this in URLMappings.groovy

```
"/**"(controller:"lab", action:"index", params:[labName:action])
```

Where I was hoping I could add the original action name to the parameters, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Any way I could have all the requests going to that controller mapped to one action, and see what the original action name would be?

Answer (score 2):

Action name is decided based on the url mapping not by the requested url.  As you are using a single action, you will always get the action name as index. Based on your requirement below are some of the options that you can choose:

- Use requested url and http method to find the right controller and action.  Not recommended.
- Use filter for setting default data
- Use filter to redirect to the default controller after saving the original controller and action in request attributes. Not recommended as it will cause multiple redirects
- Extend your controllers with the default controller and do the data setting in interceptor.

Comment: Any way to access the original URL if I map all requests to one controller?

Comment: There are different methods in HttpServletRequest to get the orig url: getPathInfo(), getServletPath(), getRequestURI(), getRequestURL(). You can look into their documentation to find out which one you need.

Comment: I ended up doing this in urlMappings: "/lab/$labname"(controller: "lab", action: "index")  which gave me the lab name as a parameter. Thanks :)